# Using TFS as a Q/A tool

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

I'm looking for a tool to track questions and answers between the development team. After then I want to compare the employees based on their activities via some reports. Currently we're using MSF for CMMI 4.2.

Is there any process template to support this situation? For example having work item types like `Question`, `Answer`, `Article`.

Is using TFS a proper tool for this purpose?

Or maybe there's some better tools available which I'm not aware about.
Is there something like StackOverflow which I can use locally in the company?

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade tfs to tfs 2013 which supports team rooms where your team members can chat which also can be used as q&a tool. You can try this now in tfs service.

http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/collaborate-in-a-team-room.aspx

You can also set up your own company wiki website where your team members can update q&a.

[What is the best ASP.NET WIKI out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177293/what-is-the-best-asp-net-wiki-out-there)

Or set up your own in house stackoverflow

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a discussion forum.  If you are using SharePoint (e.g. for the TFS Project Portal) you can create a discussion forum in SharePoint.

In TFS Work Items there is also the ability to track a discrete list of comments/discussion under the History tab.

Answer (score 0):

you can also integrate them with Microsoft Project Server Or Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

there are many tools there , waiting for you , to solve your other problem.

http://www.quantumwhisper.com/dynamics-crm-microsoft-tfs-integration/

crm has many feature for that

http://intovsts.net/2012/12/28/integration-of-dynamics-crm-2011-solutions-with-tfs/

in the project server also exist many lists like issue tracker, or risk for send messages interactive between your team and others.